# Could not able launch eclipse.exe on windows 7 64-bit OS

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

I was working on eclipse based tool. since i moved onto windows xp to window 7.
I installed my tool on windows 7 64 bit.
i could not able to launch my tool.

Please find below log.

```
!SESSION Thu Mar 15 16:40:12 CET 2012 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2012-03-15 16:40:12.287
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Comment: "windows 7 bit OS"?  Is that some exotic new version?

Comment: do u need the tool ver or windows version?

Comment: @skaffman: M$ is cutting out the code-bloat by trimming unused bits.

Comment: Windows version : Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit and Tool :IBM Product :Rational Functional Tester 8.2.iFix2

Comment: Well then, edit your post and fix the title

Comment: How are you trying to start Eclipse? How did you install it?  You're not giving us much to work with here.

Comment: I am not sure about the window latest version

Comment: this is my system windows verison :6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

Comment: i will install with IBM Product along with tool it would install automatically

Comment: when i lauch eclipse it would start with tool

Comment: if i want to work with tool first i need to start eclipse

Comment: Are you running 32-bit version Eclipse IDE with 64-bit JRE/JDK or running a 64-bit Eclipse IDE with 32-bit JRE/JDK? It won't run. Either you (1) get a 64-bit Eclipse IDE and run it with 64-bit JRE/JDK or (2) run a 32-bit Eclipse using 32-bit JRE/JDK. http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/03/05/eclipse-ide-for-64-bit-windows-and-64-bit-java/

Answer (score 1):

Windows 64-bit is a different platform from Windows (32-bit). When you build an Eclipse-based product, you have to take special steps to build it for platforms other than the one you are building on. So if you built your product on 32-bit Windows, it won't necessarily run on 64-bit Windows.

To do cross-platform export of an Eclipse-based product you'll first need the Delta Pack. Read [this](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-deltapack-in-eclipse-35.html) for the details (that blog talks about version 3.5 - make sure you get the Delta Pack for whatever version of Eclipse you are building against).

Comment: I think it is more likely a problem of trying to run 32-bit Eclipse IDE tool using 64-bit JRE/JDK or a 64-bit Eclipse IDE tool using 32-bit JRE/JDK. In either case, OP needs to confirm which version of Eclipse IDE and JRE/JDK he uses in his Windows 7 64-bit system.